# PHP - Return By-Value & By-Ref Method Overrides

Tags: php, phpstorm

I understand why it's probably bad style to override a return-by-reference method with a return-by-value method.  What about overriding a return-by-value method with a return-by-reference method?  I ask because PhpStorm detects the former but not the later.

PhpStorm calls out Sub::baseReturnsByRef as "Declaration should be compatible with super."

```
class Base {
    function & baseReturnsByRef(&$something) {
        return $something;
    }
}

class Sub extends Base {
    function baseReturnsByRef(&$something) {
        return $something;
    }
}
```

PhpStorm is mum on the following...

```
class Base {
    function baseReturnsByRef(&$something) {
        return $something;
    }
}

class Sub extends Base {
    function & baseReturnsByRef(&$something) {
        return $something;
    }
}
```

Is there an OO or other CS theory that explains why this might be ok?

Answer (score 1):

> I ask because PhpStorm detects the former but not the later

Well -- PhpStorm does the same what **PHP itself** reports (as of PHP 7.0 -- 5.6. is OK):

> Warning: Declaration of Sub::baseReturnsByRef(&$something) should be compatible with & Base::baseReturnsByRef(&$something)

This must be the change:
http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.error-handling.strict -- "Signature mismatch during inheritance"

---

> Is there an OO or other CS theory that explains why this might be ok?

Cannot properly (reliably) answer this part.

My only explanation: if function parameter accepts value and you pass the reference .. it will work, as PHP will "unreference" it for you automatically.

But ... if parameter expects a reference ... then it cannot accept the raw value.

*The same logic might be applied here:* 2nd example is OK because the return value can still be "unreferenced" automatically while it cannot be done in 1st example.